# NavigationController Push Distort Background Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have two `ViewControllers` both have have a Background Image with Height equal to the parent view of view controller.
When i `push/pop` between these `ViewController` the animation distort the background image animation when `pushing/poping` animation start.
I do not want to disable the `push/pop` animation but i also do not want this abrupt distortion of image animation as well.
My `NavigationBar` has a translucent property enabled as well as a transparent background image on `NavigationBar`.
I have set the background image on each view controller by `AutoLayouts` with Top, Leading, Trailing, Bottom with constant zero.

Comment: Can you show any code for same? And which xcode you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, I can understand that you have two view controller with background images by one you push to another one ,and when you navigate that view controller background image get distorted .
Firstly in ios 10 you should use **show** instead of **push** methods then you should use dispatch while you navigating like that -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdScreen"] animated:YES];
});
```

PS :- I dont think this would be cause by translucent property .